# Computed property with firebase element in polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an element where I receive some data from firebase which looks like that:

```
<dom-module id="my-positions-list">
 <template is="dom-bind">
  <firebase-collection data="{{aa}}"
                    location="https://myapp.firebaseio.com/positions">
  </firebase-collection>

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[aa]]" as="item"> 
   <p><span>{{url}}</span></p>
  </template>
 </template>

 <script>
  (function () {
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-positions-list',
      properties: {
        url:{
          type:String,
          computed: 'url(this.item.title)'
        }
      },
      url: function(title) {
        return "/positions/" + title;
      }
    });
  })();
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

I am trying to create a computed property "url" using the title attribute of the "item" but had no luck, any idea how to achieve that?

I also get this weird message in my console from the polymer-mini.html file:

> [my-positions-list::_prepTemplate]: top-level Polymer template must not be a type-extension, found template Move inside simple .

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The console message is caused by is="dom-bind" in your outer template. You can just remove that. This is only required if you want to use auto-binding outside of a Polymer element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<dom-module id="my-positions-list">
  <template is="dom-bind">
    <firebase-collection data="{{aa}}"
                location="https://myapp.firebaseio.com/positions/"></firebase-collection>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[aa]]"> 
      <p><span>{{url(item.title)}}</span></p>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  (function () {
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-positions-list',
      url: function(title) {
        return "/positions/" + title;
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

here the it in jsbin http://jsbin.com/lokegu/edit?html,output